# Does Tomcat or Jetty cache dynamic content?

Tags: web-server, tomcat, cache, jetty, servlet

I'm working on a Servlet app with contents that are updated periodically. Hence, between updates any dynamic pages generated by the Servlet can be cached.

Does Tomcat or Jetty (or any Servlet container) offer a way to cache dynamically generated pages?

Or would I need to use a caching reverse proxy like Squid to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they don't. I use Apache httpd with mod_proxy and mod_cache and it works pretty well. If you take the time to send proper HTTP response headers, it's better...